# NHibernate - updating Identity fields

Tags: nhibernate

Can we update Id fields in NHibernate like the following?

```
MyClass myObj = MyClass.Retrieve(1);

myObj.Id = 999;
myObj.Name = "name name";
myObj.Value = 1000;

MyClass.Update(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the session, execute raw sql to change the primary key, and then open a new session. that is the only thing that works as nhibername relies on primary key identity. you will *never* ever be able to make nhibernate do it.

Answer (score 3):

You should never change the identifier (primary key) on an existing object. With NHibernate, you should only assign the identifier on new objects if you've mapped the [generator](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) as "assigned". If you're intent is to clone an existing object, then retrieve the object and create the clone as a new instance so that a new identifier is assigned.

Comment: Why not? Changing a primary key is a terrible idea. My guess is that the original question was in regards to a cloning process.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
ISession.Delete(yourClass);
yourClass.Id = somethingelse;
ISession.Save(yourClass);
```

Why do you want to change an Identifier? 
It sounds like a very bad thing to do.

Comment: first of all, I agree - changing an identifier is a bad idea to begin with. But your "solution" here doesn't work either, if that entity has been referenced by other entities - if you have referential integrity in place, you usually cannot just simply delete a row from a table and re-create it.....

Comment: That's true, than you have to create a deep copy of the whole aggregate root

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a `Evict` after delete then work.

Something like this will work:

```
    ISession.Delete(yourClass);
    yourClass.Id = somethingelse;
    ISession.Save(yourClass);
```

Why would you want to change an Identifier? It sounds like a very bad thing to do.

This is what I did:

```
ISession.Delete(yourClass);
ISession.Evict(yourClass);
yourClass.Id = somethingelse;
ISession.Save(yourClass);
```