# How do I update the primary key using nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

The primary key for one of my tables is a string. THe string is a code which i would like to update at some point of time. How can I do this in nhibernate.
Please note there is a foreign key connected to this column which I need to cascade updates to.

For the sake of discussion let us assume my mapping is  as below

```
public class Code
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public class CodeMap : ClassMap<Code>
    {
        public CodeMap()
        {
            Table("BusinessCode");
            Id(x => x.Id, "Id");
            Map(x => x.Name, "Name").Nullable();
        }

    }
}    

public class Data
{
    public virtual int Key { get; set; }
    public virtual Code DataCode{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Desc { get; set; }
    public class DataMap : ClassMap<Data>
    {
        public DataMap()
        {
            Table("Data");
            Id(x=>x.Key,"Key");
            Map(x => x.Desc).Column("desc");
            References(x => x.Code, "BusinessCode").Nullable().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Table structure

```
BusinessCode Table
Id(nvarchar(100)) -primarykey
Name(nvarchar(1024))



Data Table
id(int) - auto generated primary key
businesscode(nvarchar(100)) - foreign key to BusinessCode Id
desc(nvarchar(1024))
```

here's the code which i use to update my object

```
using (var trans = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var modifiedSource = Session.Load<Code>(id);
                modifiedSource.Id = "newId";
                modifiedSource.Name = "new name";
                Session.Update(modifiedSource);
                trans.Commit();
            }
```

Comment: I'd just create a new object if I were you.

Comment: Probably a bad idea to go around changing primary key values on the fly. That's more of a one-time hand scripted update in my book.

Comment: I second dotjoe and @UpTheCreek: changing an object's *identity* means that it's no longer the same object. therefore- it makes sense to create a new object.

Comment: im giving in to the bad design...Wont be allowing update on primary key for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate - updating Identity fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024477/nhibernate-updating-identity-fields)

Comment: @Mulki See the cited dup question - its not possible with NHibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'assigned' [id generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id):

```
<class name="Dataset" table="Dataset" >
    <id name="id" column="id" type="String">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    ...
</class>
```

Or

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```

From NHibernate [doc](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned)

> **5.1.4.7. Assigned Identifiers**
>
> If you want the application to assign identifiers (as opposed to
>   having NHibernate generate them), you may use the assigned generator.
>   This special generator will use the identifier value already assigned
>   to the object's identifier property. Be very careful when using this
>   feature to assign keys with business meaning (almost always a terrible
>   design decision).
>
> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to
>   **explicitly specify** to NHibernate if the object should be saved or
>   updated by calling either the **Save() or Update()** method of the
>   ISession.

Comment: tried it(I load the object from DB..update both fields and use update)..throws error saying...identifier of an instance of <myclass> was altered from x to y

Comment: @Mulki: you have to be more specific, where is this thrown from, stack trace etc. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624109/identifier-of-an-instance-of-xxx-was-altered-from-y-to-z/2624350#2624350

Comment: added some code to give more details on how its updated..
iv already seen that question..im directly updating the object...not updating it through another object

Comment: @Mulki: the code that you posted should work with 'assigned'. Show the full stack trace please.

Comment: @Mulki: stack trace was thrown from Save, but in your code sample you have Update. Update should work fine for object loaded from database. See updated answer with bold emphasis.

Comment: Iv tried both actually. Im getting the same error. It looks like something is definitely wrong..I am able to save new entries but unable to update existing ones

Comment: I'd be surprised if it worked. That would mean NH needs to remember the primary key from when the object was loaded, so it can issue update like `update t set id = 4 where id = 3`

Comment: I wont be needing update on primary key for now...will reopen once i need it.

Comment: @dotjoe is Correct. Lots of research supports http://stackoverflow.com/a/1024636/11635