# How to know which object is transient

Tags: nhibernate

When you get this error with NHibernate,

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance 
before    flushing: A.B.X  -  
stack trace : at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ThrowTransientObjectException(Object obj)
```

How do you know which object is transient? In this case, `A.B.X` is linked by many other classes.

Comment: If make sense on your context, you could save that object in cascade, then you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: I prefer "save-update" instead of "all". Currently it's "none"...

Comment: if you set cascade "save-update" you shoudldn't be getting this error as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, my question is left unanswered: I wonder how to know which object is transient (and its parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you use for your primary key. If you use some numeric value you can use the method I am using in the base class of all my entities:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsTransient()
    {
        return this.Id == default(Guid);
    }
}
```

If you are using a more complex pk, which might have other [implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234145/how-do-i-update-the-primary-key-using-nhibernate), you will need to provide a more complex check.

Edit:
Then, if you want to see which entities are transient before saving them, for debugging, if you have some kind of a class which does data access, say a repository, before the save you can traverse the object graph of the entity to be saved. It is doable with a bit of reflection, just recursively walk all the collections and properties of the entity, if they all inherit from the same base class cast them and call the IsTransient() method.

This is somewhat complicated, and I do wish NH told us which object was transient more precisely.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how it will help me. The error is thrown when we flush the NHibernate session. So we don't know which object is transient, only its type.

Comment: Oh! That was the question :) Edited my answer.

Comment: What would that 'more complex' check be for composite IDs, especially where the composite ID has a reference another entity.?